# Are key scramblers effective in beating keyloggers?

Tags: keylogger

Looking around online for a way to beat keyloggers, I encountered the term 'key scrambler'. My search for the term here on superuser.com didn't yield any result ... hence the question

Are key scramblers effective in beating keyloggers?

Comment: i assume you are trying to beat software keyloggers, right ? not hardware ones that sit on the keyboard wire. You may find something like two factor authentication with something like a yubico key helps.

Comment: +1: Hardware didn't even occur to me ... Good call!

Comment: Hardware ones are more common in my experience. They are incredibly easy to fit, very unobtrusive and remain even if the PC is re-imaged or clean installed. Plus how often do you check the back of your machine or your keyboard cable?

Comment: Best way to beat software keyloggers is to do an offline scan for them on a regular basis.

Answer (score 1):

Keyloggers usually install in the OS in the middle of the flow where the key is pressed and the action that the OS does with this key stroke.

There are some ways you can try to beat a key logger, but these don't beat all of them.
Some home banking web sites use a software keyboard to enter your password, this input isn't caught by a keylogger.

Another way is to use specially designed software to detect wich software has a keyboard hook (that means software which listens to every keyboard event in Windows), but i don't know of any examples.

Comment: Building on the first part of your response; my concern is that if key-scrambler intercepts the keyboard/character queue - couldn't a keylogger do the same?

Comment: @Everyone: It could, but most keyloggers just do it once as soon as possible, and then don't bother with reactivating the hooks.